# Build a Regex for markup

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to build a regex for template markup tags.

Right now the markups are something like this:

```
{{ account.name }}
{{ account.email }}
```

And this is the current Regex i build for it

```
/{{ [a-z_.]* }}/i
```

And now, i need to include markup tags with a certain modifier in this case the encoded option, which can be optional. So it would be something like:

```
{{ account.email|encoded }}
```

So the regex would be something like:

```
/{{ [a-z_.]*(|encode)? }}/i
```

But for some reason I can get it work.

Any ideas or comments on how to resolve this?

Comment: You have to escape the pipe and use encoded `{{ [a-z_.]*(\|encoded)? }}` See https://regex101.com/r/c3WJKm/1

Comment: _"Any ideas or comments on how to resolve this?"_ Yeah, just use Twig. :)

Comment: ^ Seriously, unless this is for a school project or something, why re-invent the wheel?